# If $u$ and $v$ have the same order, $u=f(\tau)(v)$ iff $v=g(\tau)(u)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, modules

Suppose $\tau\in L(V)$, for $V$ a finite dimensional vector space, and $p(x)$ is an irreducible factor of the minimal polynomial $m_\tau(x)$. Also, suppose $u,v\in V$, and both $u$ and $v$ has order $p(x)$, when regarding $V$ as an $F[x]$ module defined by $f(x) v=f(\tau)(v)$. That is, the ideal $(p(x))$ is the annihilator of both $u$ and $v$.

I'm trying to prove that $u=f(\tau)(v)$ for some $f(x)$ iff $v=g(\tau)(u)$ for some $g(x)$.

I suppose $u=f(\tau)(v)=f(x)v$. Then $p(x)u=p(x)f(x)v=0$. This implies $p(\tau)(f(\tau)(v))=0$. Does this allow us to find some factorization of $p(\tau)$ or something? I'd appreciate any ideas to tackle this problem.

I'm selfstudying Advanced Linear Algebra by Roman, and it is the last problem of chapter 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\rm u=f(x)v$, we cannot have $\rm p(x)\mid f(x)$; multiply by any inverse $\rm g(x)$ to $\rm f(x)$ modulo $\rm p(x)$.